# Firebase: Getting all child elements that match value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a system such that users are assigned tickets, and I get all tickets that are assigned for such user. [image: 1] [image: 2]

So, a user may be assigned 5 different tickets on 3 different projects. I am trying to fetch all tickets where the field of "assignee" equals [Name of user]. The screenshots I showed are the projectTickets for just one project. I need a way to fetch what I requested, and above it, put a for loop to go through every project. In every project name (d0c), there is a collection titled "projectTickets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all projectTickets across all projects where 'assignee' = 'aa', use this:

```
db.collectionGroup("projectTickets").where("assignee", "==", "aa")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        // below is your loop
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

This will require indexes.

For user named 'aa', the above function should get all tickets on all projects.

Comment: That is working! However, if I want to change "aa" to say a var called name, it will not work.

Comment: So glad I could help. The query is case sensitive, so make sure that the variable is exactly right. For example, you can set `var name = "aa"` and check if it fetches the data.